# Log viewer doesn't work on JBoss 7.1 management console running in docker

Tags: java, docker, jboss, dockerfile, jboss-eap-7

I am running docker on my local machine using eap71-openshift from redhat as my base image. When I log in to the management console and try to use the log viewer I can download the logs but I can't view them. Chrome's dev tools says that the request "stalled" and there is the following message in the console.

```
app-102.js:231 GET http://localhost:9990/management/subsystem/logging/log-file/server.log?operation=attribute&name=stream&useStreamAsResponse 0 ()
```

I can copy the url above into a new tab and it will return the log. If I run EAP 7.1 directly on my machine without docker the functionality works as expected.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-eap-7/eap71-openshift
RUN $JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh jbossadmin P@ssw0rd --silent
EXPOSE 9990
CMD ["/opt/eap/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

There are no errors in the JBoss server log.

Has anyone come across this? Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to view it and download it with that same docker file. Maybe it's some kind of permissions issue? Do you run Docker as root?

Comment: You might be on to something. I am building the docker image from a windows host and I remember a message about explicitly setting file permissions when I ran the docker build.